# When saving Group with Mailchimp settings - nothing happens

Tags: extension, mailchimp

I have weird issue with [Civi Mailchimp extension](https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp).
By looking at instructions after setting up API key, I need to update Civi Group which to be synced to Mailchimp. However, when saving group after change it doesn't affect at all and no error message.
Changes to Group:
[image]

Save Success message:

[image]

And when visit back to Group again:

[image]

Another issue is with Interest Sync:
I can select List and Groups from the drop down, but hit error message.
[image]

But after save:

[image]

Any one have idea around these issue?
Thanks,